# Handling optional parameters in main

Tags: c++, parameters, program-entry-point, optional-parameters

Suppose I have a main function which basically just calls one other function as entry point to the program. The function (and thus the full program) has a number of mandatory and a number of optional parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void function_to_call(std::string arg1,
                  std::string arg2,
                  std::string arg3,
                  std::string arg4,
                  std::string arg5 = "foo",
                  std::string arg6 = "bar",
                  int num1 = 1,
                  int num2 = 2
                  )

{
  // do fancy stuff here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  int num1, num2;

  std::stringstream stream;

  if( argc < 5 ) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: \n\t" << argv[0]
              << "\n\t\t1st argument"
              << "\n\t\t2nd argument"
              << "\n\t\t3rd argument"
              << "\n\t\t4th argument"
              << "\n\t\t5th argument (optional)"
              << "\n\t\t6th argument (optional)"
              << "\n\t\t7th argument (optional)"
              << "\n\t\t8th argument (optional)"
              << "\n\t\t9th argument (optional)" << std::endl;
  }
  if( argc == 5 ) {
    function_to_call( argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4] );
  }
  if( argc == 6 ) {
    function_to_call( argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5] );
  }
  if( argc == 7 ) {
    function_to_call( argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], argv[6] );
  }
  if( argc == 8 ) {
    stream << argv[7];
    stream >> num1;
    function_to_call( argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], argv[6], num1 );
  }
  if( argc == 9 ) {
    stream << argv[7] << ' ' << argv[8];
    stream >> num1 >> num2;
    function_to_call( argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], argv[6], num1, num2 );
  }

  return 0;

}
```

The `if` chain could maybe be replaced with a `switch`, the command line might be tidied up a bit by using the `getopt` library or boost `program_options`, but that doesn't really change things conceptually.

Is there an obvious way I am missing to handle different numbers of parameters?

Comment: First things coming to mind is a loop and a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: You should consider a `get options` implementation (maybe gnu getopt or boost::options)

Comment: Or have local variables that hold the defaults for the omitted parameters (and will be changed of those parameters are passed in), then you'd only need on function call.

Comment: In what way do you believe that it doesn't change things conceptually? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RobertPrévost I admit that I didn't look at all of the details of boosts `program_options` which seems to allow for any number of things (though I often shy away from including boost as (for whatever reason) it seems to often be not wanted/not available on centrally maintained servers... at least what I read in quite a few questions on SO). The conceptual things I meant was that I still need (in non-boost solutions) quite a number of `if`s (or the like) to handle parameters present or changed from their default. The different function calls one can avoid as @1201ProgramAlarm pointed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize one way of doing this might be to use vector of a (trivial) base class and then have small specializations for the different types e.g. like this (not necessarily optimal):

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void set(const char *) = 0;
};

class Int : public Base {
public:
  Int(int value) : value_(value) {}
  Int(const char* value) : value_(std::stoi(value)) {}
  virtual void set(const char* value) { value_ = std::stoi(value); }
  int get() { return value_; }
private:
  int value_;
};

class Str : public Base {
public:
  Str(const char* value): value_(value) {}
  virtual void set(const char* value) { value_ = value; }
  std::string get() { return value_; }
private:
  std::string value_;
};
```

Then the option parsing could be done like this, i.e. have the compiler figure out which type we are dealing with

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  std::vector<Base*> theopts = { new Str(""),new Str(""),new Str(""),new Str(""),new Str("foo"),new Str("bar"),new Int(1),new Int(2) };

  if( argc < 5 ) {
     // put meaningful handling here
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < argc-1; ++i ) {
    theopts[i]->set(argv[i+1]);
  }

  function_to_call( static_cast<Str*>(theopts[0])->get(),
                    static_cast<Str*>(theopts[1])->get(),
                    static_cast<Str*>(theopts[2])->get(),
                    static_cast<Str*>(theopts[3])->get(),
                    static_cast<Str*>(theopts[4])->get(),
                    static_cast<Str*>(theopts[5])->get(),
                    static_cast<Int*>(theopts[6])->get(),
                    static_cast<Int*>(theopts[7])->get()
                    );
}
```

The function call then obviously is a bit ugly due to the explicit casting, but the number of explicit `if`s is very small in this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The command line parameter array is *null terminated* so you could parse it one element at a time like this:

```
void function_to_call(std::string arg1,
                  std::string arg2,
                  std::string arg3,
                  int num1,
                  int num2
                  )

{
  // do fancy stuff here
    std::cout << "arg1: " << arg1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "arg2: " << arg2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "arg3: " << arg3 << '\n';
    std::cout << "num1: " << num1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "num2: " << num2 << '\n';
}

struct config
{
    std::string arg1;
    std::string arg2;
    std::string arg3 = "wibble"; // set arg3 default here
    int arg4 = 1;                // set arg4 default here
    int arg5 = 0;                // set arg5 default here
};

config parse_command_params(char** argv)
{
    config cfg;

    if(!argv[1])
        throw std::runtime_error("At least 2 args required");

    cfg.arg1 = argv[1];

    if(!argv[2])
        throw std::runtime_error("At least 2 args required");

    cfg.arg2 = argv[2];

    // optional from here on

    if(!argv[3])
        return cfg;

    cfg.arg3 = argv[3];

    if(!argv[4])
        return cfg;

    cfg.arg4 = std::stoi(argv[4]);

    if(!argv[5])
        return cfg;

    cfg.arg5 = std::stoi(argv[5]);

    return cfg;
}

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        config cfg = parse_command_params(argv);

        function_to_call(cfg.arg1, cfg.arg2, cfg.arg3, cfg.arg4, cfg.arg5);
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

By storing the parameters in a `struct` I can use it to set the default values for the optional parameters and simply ignore them if they are not present in the parameters supplied by the user.

**Note:** Edited to include @cmaster's suggestion moving parsing to a dedicated function.

Comment: I would like to add that you can avoid the `if(argv[3])`-arrow in the lower part by moving the parameter parsing into a dedicated function: This would allow you to simply return early by means of `if(!argv[3]) return; cfg.arg3 = argv[3]; ...`

Comment: @cmaster Yes that makes the optional parameters less error prone if you forget to nest them - *like I did in my original post.* :)

Answer (score 2):

[Boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/program_options.html) is a library that can be very helpful in parsing input arguments.  In particular, arguments can be specified to take on default values if they are not specified on the command line.  If default arguments were specified as they are in function_to_call, then the big if-elseif block can be replaced with one function call.  Additionally, boost program options allows the user to specify the type of the argument.  This would avoid having to parse the integers using std::stringstream.  Finally, while this may not be particularly desired, the more robust handling of default arguments by Boost program options would allow for the full set of choices for passing or not passing the optional arguments to function_to_call.  As it now stands, the arguments to function_to_call have to be specified fully from left to right despite the fact that the last four arguments are all optional.

Comment: Is this copy and paste?

Comment: No, it is purely what I know from experience using it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is a quick and dirty way of achieving an easily scaleable list of options, you could attempt something along the lines of the following. It has the added benefit that you can define the default values for the optional parameters and include those default values in the print out. It also means whenever you want to add additional required or optional arguments, you just need to add them to the list in the `DefineRequiredArgs` or `DefineOptionalArgs` methods and you have access to them in other places.

```
// multi_option_helper.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void function_to_call(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &req_args,
                      std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &opt_args,
                      int num1 = 1,
                      int num2 = 2
                      )

{
    // do fancy stuff here

    // Print required options
    std::cout << "Required Options:\n" ;
    for (int i=0; i<req_args.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "\t" << req_args[i][0] << " = " << req_args[i][1] << std::endl;
    }
    // Print optional options
    std::cout << "Optional Options:\n" ;
    for (int i=0; i<opt_args.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "\t" << opt_args[i][0] << " = " << opt_args[i][1] << std::endl;
    }

}

std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > DefineRequiredArgs()
{
    // Define the required arguments
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > req_args ;

    /* pre-c++11 way of doing it */
    // Define a generic vector of strings
    std::vector<std::string> arg(2) ;
    arg[1] = "" ;
    arg[0] = "1st_argument" ;
    req_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "2nd_argument" ;
    req_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "3rd_argument" ;
    req_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "4th_argument" ;
    req_args.push_back(arg) ;
    // ... continue this process as many times as needed

    /* post-c++11 way of doing it
     req_args.push_back({"1st_argument", ""}) ;
     req_args.push_back({"2nd_argument", ""}) ;
     req_args.push_back({"3rd_argument", ""}) ;
     req_args.push_back({"4th_argument", ""}) ;
     */

    return req_args ;
}

std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > DefineOptionalArgs()
{
    // Define the required arguments
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > opt_args ;

    // pre-c++11
    std::vector<std::string> arg(2) ;
    arg[1] = "" ;
    arg[0] = "5th_argument" ;
    arg[1] = "foo" ;
    opt_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "6th_argument" ;
    arg[1] = "bar" ;
    opt_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "7th_argument" ;
    arg[1] = "521600" ;
    opt_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "8th_argument" ;
    arg[1] = "86" ;
    opt_args.push_back(arg) ;
    arg[0] = "9th_argument" ;
    arg[1] = "somethingelse" ;
    opt_args.push_back(arg) ;
    // ... continue this process as many times as needed

    /* c++11 alternative
     opt_args.push_back({"5th_argument", "foo"}) ;
     opt_args.push_back({"6th_argument", "bar"}) ;
     opt_args.push_back({"7th_argument", "521600"}) ;
     opt_args.push_back({"8th_argument", "86"}) ;
     opt_args.push_back({"9th_argument", "somethingelse"}) ;
     */

    return opt_args ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Get the required options
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > req_args = DefineRequiredArgs() ;
    // Get the optionsl options
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > opt_args = DefineOptionalArgs() ;

    if( argc < req_args.size()+1 ) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: \n\t" << argv[0] ;
        // Print the required arguments
        for (int i=0; i<req_args.size(); i++) {
            std::cerr << "\n\t" << req_args[i][0] ;
        }
        // Print the optional arguments
        for (int i=0; i<req_args.size(); i++) {
            std::cerr << "\n\t" << opt_args[i][0]
            << " (optional Default=" << opt_args[i][1] << ")" ;
        }
        std::cerr << std::endl;
    } else {
        // Fill the required options
        int opt_counter(1) ;
        while ((opt_counter <= req_args.size())) {
            req_args[opt_counter-1][1] = std::string(argv[opt_counter]) ;
            opt_counter++ ;
        }
        // Now fill the optional options
        int offset(req_args.size()+1) ; // Note the additional offset of '1'
        while ((opt_counter < argc)) {
            opt_args[opt_counter-offset][1] = std::string(argv[opt_counter]) ;
            opt_counter++ ;
        }
        // Fill num1 and num2
        int num1, num2 ;
        std::stringstream stream ;
        stream << opt_args[2][1] << ' ' << opt_args[3][1] ;
        stream >> num1 >> num2 ;

        /* c++11 alternative
        int num1 = std::stoi(opt_args[2][1]) ;
        int num2 = std::stoi(opt_args[3][1]) ;
        */
        // Now call the helper function
        function_to_call(req_args, opt_args, num1, num2) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when you run with fewer than the required number of options you get the print out:

```
Usage: 
    ./multi_option_helper
    1st_argument
    2nd_argument
    3rd_argument
    4th_argument
    5th_argument (optional Default=foo)
    7th_argument (optional Default=521600)
    8th_argument (optional Default=86)
    9th_argument (optional Default=somethingelse)
```

Note that since the tag is only "c++" and not "c++11" I've only included code that will compile doing `g++ multi_option_helper.cpp -o multi_option_helper`, however there are a few C++11 alternatives commented out which simplify things.

On the other hand, if what you're looking for is something that is a bit more involved, something that allows you to create named options (`--Arg1=arg1_val` for example) you may have a look at 'GetOpt'. One benefit of this is the ability of your user to pass the parameters in any order they want. You can also create a help option (typically this is the `-h` or `--help` option in some programs).

**Personal note:** I tend to shy away from using the BOOST methods because they add an additional dependency to my code. Either I have to include the header files in my package (I'm not sure what kind of licensing BOOST uses, so this may not even be legal), or require the user to go and download them, then load the library themselves. This is why I prefer GetOpt, since most people using modern compilers should already have access to it. I've also developed my own command line option handler class to make defining and using command line options easier for myself. Check it out [here](https://github.com/Jvinniec/CLOptions/) if you're interested.